# $ionicpopup onTap does not work

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-popup

I'm developing a phonegap app. I want to get users comments via $ionicpopup the code is as below:

```
function showToast(message) {
        if (window.plugins && window.plugins.toast) {
            window.plugins.toast.showLongCenter(message);
        }
        else $ionicLoading.show({ template: message, noBackdrop: true, duration: 2000 });
    }
    $scope.showPopup = function () {
        $scope.data = {};
        var pop=$ionicPopup.show({
            template: '<div class="list" dir="rtl"><label class="item item-input"><input ng-model="cmnt.name" type="text" placeholder="name"></label><label class="item item-input"><textarea ng-model="cmnt.body" rows="4" placeholder="      comment..."></textarea></label></div>',
            title: 'write your comment',
            subTitle: '',
            scope: $scope,
            buttons: [
              {
                  text: 'cancel',
                  type: 'button-small'

              },
              {
                  text: '<b>save</b>',
                  type: 'button-energized',
                  onTap: function (e) {
                      return $scope.cmnt;

                  }
              }
            ]
        }).then(function (res) {
            jQuery.post(mysite + "home/addComment",
                      { registerID: localStorage.getItem("regID"), name: res.name, body:res.body, gameID: $scope.gameID })
                      .success(function (text) {
                          result = JSON.stringify(text);
                          showToast('result');
                      }).error(function (e) {
                          showToast("Error! ");
                      })
        });


    }
```

but when "Save" button is clicked nothing will happen. why is that? what is wrong???
ps:I found out that the problem is with "return $scope.cmnt" but i dont know how to solve it.

Comment: Please take a look @ http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/

Comment: I followed the link you suggested. they have exactly the same syntax but my code still not works! :(

Comment: can you create plnkr or fiddle so that i can take a look ? what error that gives exactly?

Comment: I made a codepen http://codepen.io/shivarad/pen/RRrkjE . the problem is that after clicking the save button nothing happens.

Comment: I found out that the problem is with "return $scope.cmnt" ; but I dont know how to solve it!!!!

Comment: @ShivaRowshanrad, You forgot to inject $ionicLoading inside controller. Might be that will help you.